# COM - Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

Tags: com

I've got a very strange issue happening and will try describe this as best as I can.

So I have a COM object which I've registered correctly and then reference from my test application. I then create an object (called Connection) and populate it with the connection details. Next I then call "connection.CreateTransaction()". This will go off to the COM, create and return the object for me to then utilize. So I run this and it works fine. This is a windows forms application.

Now, I need to be able to connect to this app using remoting, so I've put all the code in place for this, and I still have the ability to run the "connection.CreateTransaction()" directly from the application too. So now, when I use the remoting logic, I get to the "connection.CreateTransaction()" and get the following error:

"Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))."

However when I run the logic directly from the application, i.e. not with remoting, it passes this step and sends the transaction to the client application via the COM interface.

I'm at an absolute loss as to how this can work from the app, and then using the same code, just sending the data via remoting it fails.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by "remoting". If you mean you have a COM server registered on one machine and the COM client running on the other, then be aware that the server's type library must be registered on the client machine, for marshaling.

Comment: Apologies, I meant that I was using .net remoting to connect the one application to the second application, however they are both running on the same machine. The second application then does all the loading logic, the first simply sends a list of trades to load (in string format).

Comment: Is the server perhaps registered per-user, and under remoting the COM-using application runs under a different user account than when you run it normally? I must admit I know very little about .NET, and less still about its remoting.